# Groupby category then do divisions for new year over old year

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, division, rolling-computation

Sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000,1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000],
                   'Group':['A', 'A', 'A','A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                         'Col_1':[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200],
                         'Col_2':[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 199, 299, 399]})
```

I'd like to create a new column by dividing one year by its previous year in Col_1 and Col_2 respectively for each group. Then, divide the two divisions. See example below:

| Year | Group | Col_1 | Col_2 | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1995 | A | 100 | 11 | NA |
| 1996 | A | 200 | 22 | (200/100)/(22/11) |
| 1997 | A | 300 | 33 | (300/200)/(33/22) |
| 1998 | A | 400 | 44 | ............. |
| 1999 | A | 500 | 55 | ............. |
| 2000 | A | 600 | 66 | ............. |
| 1995 | B | 700 | 77 | NA |
| 1996 | B | 800 | 88 | (800/700)/(88/77) |
| 1997 | B | 900 | 99 | (900/800)/(99/88) |
| 1998 | B | 1000 | 199 | ............. |
| 1999 | B | 1100 | 299 | ............. |
| 2000 | B | 1200 | 399 | ............. |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-requisite is that Year is sorted and that no years are missing. You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) "Group" compute the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and divide the resulting columns using [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

### division of division

```
df['New Column'] = (df.groupby('Group')[['Col_1','Col_2']]
                      .pct_change().add(1)
                      .eval('Col_1/Col_2')
                   )
```

output:

```
    Year Group  Col_1  Col_2  New Column
0   1995     A    100     11         NaN
1   1996     A    200     22    1.000000
2   1997     A    300     33    1.000000
3   1998     A    400     44    1.000000
4   1999     A    500     55    1.000000
5   2000     A    600     66    1.000000
6   1995     B    700     77         NaN
7   1996     B    800     88    1.000000
8   1997     B    900     99    1.000000
9   1998     B   1000    199    0.552764
10  1999     B   1100    299    0.732107
11  2000     B   1200    399    0.817498
```

### division of difference (initial question)

```
df['New Column'] = (df.groupby('Group')[['Col_1','Col_2']]
                      .diff()
                      .eval('Col_1/Col_2')
                   )
```

output:

```
    Year Group  Col_1  Col_2  New Column
0   1995     A    100     11         NaN
1   1996     A    200     22    9.090909
2   1997     A    300     33    9.090909
3   1998     A    400     44    9.090909
4   1999     A    500     55    9.090909
5   2000     A    600     66    9.090909
6   1995     B    700     77         NaN
7   1996     B    800     88    9.090909
8   1997     B    900     99    9.090909
9   1998     B   1000    199    1.000000
10  1999     B   1100    299    1.000000
11  2000     B   1200    399    1.000000
```

Comment: You could do without the temp column: `df['New Column'] = df.groupby('Group')[['Col_1','Col_2']].diff().eval('Col_1/Col_2')`

Comment: You could skip the `eval` with `df.groupby('Group')[['Col_1', 'Col_2']].diff().agg(np.divide.reduce, 1)` (although the `eval` is shorter and more pleasing to the eyes)

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks, very nice to know! I wished a few times already that pandas would have the equivalent of `diff` for division, at least for consecutive cols/rows. NB. this fails with *TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc true_divide* if the column type is `int`

Comment: I'm so sorry. I miswrote the methodology. It should be the division of two divisions. How would I approach that? Please see my updates above if it doesn't make sense to you. @mozway

Comment: @Jamie I updated the answer (I kept both options for completeness)

Comment: Thank you, @mozway! May I know why we need this ".add(1)" ?

Comment: `pct_change` calculates a percent change, so 100->200 is 1 (100%), and you want 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235863/discussion-between-jamie-and-mozway).